# ProfileDirectory неправильно возвращает путь профиля Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

После объявления 
`new FirefoxDriver(ds0, options);`

`options.Profile.ProfileDirectory`
возвращает следующую строку:

```
C:\Users\yuser\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous.8de001f7ee904dc29cc1fa565b22b2fa.webdriver-profile
```

Этой папки нигде не существует.
На самом деле профиль создается совсем по другому пути

```
C:\Users\yuser\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.drr02LHgjz1V
```

Как узнать именно этот, "настоящий" путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ни странно, оно выдает тебе правильный и настоящий путь ко временному профилю селениума.

Селениум создает временный профиль при каждом запуске драйвера по дэфолту. Если ты хочешь использовать свой собственный (уже существующий профиль), ты должен это прописать в настройки при создании драйвера.

Например так:

```
var a = new FirefoxDriver("C:\Users\Kiya\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\klhly0ca.defaul");
```

---

UPD:

```
var profiletmp= driver.Capabilities.GetCapability("moz:profile").ToString();
```

Comment: Папки, путь которой возвращает ''options.Profile.ProfileDirectory", просто не существует, хотя она должна существовать как минимум до закрытия инстанса.

Comment: да, до закрытия инстанса она должна сущестовать. И именно по тому адресу и именно с таким шаблоном названия -- `anonymous.наборбуквицифр.webdriver-profile`.

Comment: Мож с последними версиями Мазилы изменилось что то, у меня временный профиль создается в  ́rust_mozprofile.наборбуквицифр ́. И этот путь без костылей не могу получить.

Comment: тогда попробуй `var profiletmp= driver.Capabilities.GetCapability("moz:profile").ToString();`

Comment: да, это решение

Comment: Не забывай отмечать ответы которые тебе помогли. В том числе и в более ранниих вопросах.